# copy "levels" from a file

Tags: python

I need to write a function that read a file and put in list every level of a game in 1 cell.
every cell contains the rows of the level as strings, and every row is an element of the cell.
The final cell should be without the numbers or the words that appears before the level and without "\n" or empty cells.
I implemented this function, but it not working so well for levels looking like this.
some have  any idea?

level from the file

```
; 1

####
# .#
#  ###
#*@  #
#  $ #
#  ###
####
```

as cell in the list:

```
['####', '# .#', '#  ###', '#*@  #', '#  $ #', '#  ###', '####']
```

example of levels I have problem with:

```
; 154 'Take the long way home.'

 ############################
 #                          #
 # ######################## #
 # #                      # #
 # # #################### # #
 # # #                  # # #
 # # # ################ # # #
 # # # #              # # # #
 # # # # ############ # # # #
 # # # # #            # # # #
 # # # # # ############ # # #
 # # # # #              # # #
 # # # # ################ # #
 # # # #                  # #
##$# # #################### #
#. @ #                      #
#############################
```

looking somthing like this:

```
["54 'Take the long way home.'", '', ' ############################', ' #                          #', ' # ######################## #', ' # #                      # #', ' # # #################### # #', ' # # #                  # # #', ' # # # ################ # # #', ' # # # #              # # # #', ' # # # # ############ # # # #', ' # # # # #            # # # #', ' # # # # # ############ # # #', ' # # # # #              # # #', ' # # # # ################ # #', ' # # # #                  # #', '##$# # #################### #', '#. @ #                      #', '#############################']
```

my code:

```
def loader(filename):

    tmp=[]
    levels=[]
    f=open(filename, "r")
    f=f.read().split(';')
    for line in f:
        tmp.append(line[2:].strip())
    tmp.remove("")
    for i in tmp:
        i=i.split("\n")
        levels.append(i)
    print levels
```

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: I added an output after the problematic levels.
I get cells that I dont need,with word, numbers ot empty

Comment: That example output doesn't fit the example input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kinda hard to follow exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but I think this function will give you what you want.

```
def loader(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    header = lines[0] # don't know if you need this
    level = lines[2:]
    f.close()
    return level
```

Edit:
Oh, I didn't realize that there were multiple levels per file.

How about this then:

```
def loader(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    levels = f.read().split(';')[1:]
    return [level.strip().split('\n')[2:] for level in levels]
```

Comment: I just need eventually get a "clean" level, just the rows that contains game board, without the numbers before or the names of the levels or empty lines

Comment: That's what I thought, did you try my answer?

Comment: @user1659937 a file contains multiple levels, I think.

Comment: Edited for multiple levels per file.

Answer (score 0):

```
def loader(filename):

    tmp=[]
    levels=[]
    f=open(filename, "r")
    f=f.read().split(';')
    for i in f[1:]:
        i=i.split("\n")
        levels.append(i[2:-1])
    print levels
```

Works fine for me:

testinput.txt:

```
; 1

####
# .#
#  ###
#*@  #
#  $ #
#  ###
####
; 154 'Take the long way home.'

 ############################
 #                          #
 # ######################## #
 # #                      # #
 # # #################### # #
 # # #                  # # #
 # # # ################ # # #
 # # # #              # # # #
 # # # # ############ # # # #
 # # # # #            # # # #
 # # # # # ############ # # #
 # # # # #              # # #
 # # # # ################ # #
 # # # #                  # #
##$# # #################### #
#. @ #                      #
#############################
```

Output:

```
[['####', '# .#', '#  ###', '#*@  #', '#  $ #', '#  ###', '####'], [' ############################', ' #                          #', ' # ######################## #', ' # #                      # #', ' # # #################### # #', ' # # #                  # # #', ' # # # ################ # # #', ' # # # #              # # # #', ' # # # # ############ # # # #', ' # # # # #            # # # #', ' # # # # # ############ # # #', ' # # # # #              # # #', ' # # # # ################ # #', ' # # # #                  # #', '##$# # #################### #', '#. @ #                      #', '#############################']]
```

Comment: Note the [2:] in the `levels.append` line. I added example output to show that it works.

Comment: OK, if you want to remove the trailing empty cell you need to add `:-1` in the slicing of the level lines. Edited.